# If else condition using Robot Framework with Variables assignment

Tags: if-statement, variables, return, robotframework, keyword

I'm getting an error, when I trying to assign a value and return. I'm using Pycharm and selenium library

Here is the code

```
Get Search Text Data
    [arguments]  ${TotalRecords}

Run Keyword IF
    ...     ${TotalRecords}>3       ${Searchrow}= set variable  ${TotalRecords}-1
    ...     ELSE    ${Searchrow}= set variable  ${TotalRecords}

[Return]  ${Searchrow}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Run Keyword If ${TotalRecords}>3, ${Searchrow}= set variable, ${TotalRecords}-1, ELSE, ${Searchrow}= set variable, ${TotalRecords}
```

Documentation:
Runs the given keyword with the given arguments, if condition is true.

```
Start / End / Elapsed:  20211231 09:10:24.057 / 20211231 09:10:24.059 / 00:00:00.002
09:10:24.059    FAIL    Variable '${Searchrow}' not found.
```

I'm learning this now.

Comment: It looks like you don't have two spaces between `${Searchrow}=` and `set variable`. Is that how it is in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do assignments as part of an `ELSE` statement. Robot will think that `${Searchrow}= set variable` is the name of a keyword, and since `${Searchrow}` doesn't already exist, it throws an error because it can't figure out what the keyword is supposed to be.

Instead, use [Set variable if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If)

```
${Searchrow}=  Set variable if  ${TotalRecords}>3  ${TotalRecords}-1  ${TotalRecords}
```